# reducing time complexity of compare two characters in one single string in c++

Tags: c++, string, time, compare

I have to compare first letter of a string with other letters of string in c++
for ex: in "bsadasdaddgkoj"
i have to compare b i.e first letter to all other letters and see if it is alphabetically smaller
but i have to do this really quick

```
vector<string> possibleChanges(vector<string> usernames) {
int n=usernames.size();
 vector<string> answers(n);
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
     for(int j=1;j<usernames[i].size();j++) {
        if(usernames[i][0] > usernames[i][j]){
            answers[i] = "YES";
            break;
        }
    }
    if(answers[i]!="YES") answers[i]="NO";
 }
 return answers;
}
```

i have tried this so far this works but it is really slow.

Comment: Any reason to use `std::string` instead of `bool`?

Comment: You pass your `std::vector` by copy... Use const reference instead.

Comment: @Jarod42 that's not the issue . However yeah i got to use string as to where I am suing this.

Comment: have you enabled compiler optimisations? How slow is "really slow"?

Comment: If you use a `std::vector<bool>` for the answers, you could easily have a check in the code using the vector, to print either `"YES"` or `"NO"`. Then you could initialize the vector to all false, and only set to true in the `usernames[i][0] > usernames[i][j` check. And remove the second `if` in the shown code. And for even greater run-time efficiency, you could use a `std::vector<int>` for the answers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure bottleneck is not in the comparison, but in your extra copy and/or string usage. Have you profiled your code?

Comment: why do you expect that time complexity can be reduced? You cannot check every character without traversing every character

Comment: btw your code does not match the description. You say you need to compare first letter to all other letters, but the code only looks for the first that compares smaller

Comment: From a quick experiment the vast majority of the execution time of this code taken up by copying `usernames` into the function (changing to a reference is approx 4 times faster) and creating the strings in `answers` (changing to `vector<bool>` is approx another 4 times faster)

Comment: Do you really need to gather all answers in a vector, or can you process one string at a time? For instance, `for (const auto& n: names) std::cout << (n.find(n[0], 1) != n.npos ? "YES" : "NO") << endl;`

Comment: @molbdnilo all answers in on string, sorry :(

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it's part of test on a platform and its showing time limit exceeded message on big inputs

Comment: @Jarod42 can you please give a link to code profiling I'm unfamiliar with the concept little new to programming. Although it will help a tons if I can test and debug performance issue of my programs . I face this problem in other programs i write too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you really need answers as strings...

```
vector<string> possibleChanges(const vector<string>& usernames) {
 const size_t n = usernames.size();
 vector<string> answers(n, "NO");
 for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    auto firstChar = usernames[i][0];
    auto it = std::find_if(usernames[i].begin() + 1, usernames[i].end(), [&firstChar](std::string::value_type ch) { return firstChar > ch; });
    if (it != usernames[i].end())
       answers[i] = "YES";
 }
 return answers;
}
```

Also, if you know that `usernames[i].size()` >= 2 (or 4, or 8...), you could apply loop unrolling like:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
         auto firstChar = usernames[i][0];
         size_t j = 1;
         bool flag = false;
         for (; j + 4 < usernames[i].size(); j += 4) {
            if (firstChar > usernames[i][j] ||
               firstChar > usernames[i][j + 1] ||
               firstChar > usernames[i][j + 2] ||
               firstChar > usernames[i][j + 3]) 
            {
               answers[i] = "YES";
               flag = true;
               break;
            }
               
         }
         for (; j < usernames[i].size() && !flag; ++j) {
            if (firstChar > usernames[i][j]) {
               answers[i] = "YES";
               break;
            }
         }
```

Comment: works but still slow

Comment: than  loop unrolling will help you

Comment: updated for loop unrolling...